# Remove full name from user-defined Exception

Tags: python, exception

I have defined my own functional python Exception:

```
class MyError(Exception):
def __init__(self, value):
    self.value = value
def __str__(self):
    return repr(self.value)
```

And when I raise it I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

--snip--

    raise MyError("Test")
src.exceptions.MyError: 'Test'
```

How would I remove the "src.exceptions" before the Exception name, while keeping the actual Exception name, like the in-box Exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

Best way to define custom exceptions in python is derive a class from `Exception` and then use this class as Base class for defining user-defined exceptions.

```
class MyErrorBase(Exception):
    pass


class MyError(MyErrorBase):

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __str__(self):
        return repr(self.value)

try:
    raise MyError("Test")
except MyError, exc:
    print exc
```

this will give output as :

`Test`